# Dictionary with tuples key: All tuples with the same first element

Tags: python, search, tuples, key

I have dictionary in python whose keys are tuples, like:

```
my-dict={(1,'a'):value1, (1,'b'):value2, (1,'c'):value3, (2,'a'):value4, 
(2,'b'):value5,(3,'a'):value6}
```

I need to access all values whose keys have the same first argument. For example, I need to access

```
{(1,'a'):value1, (1,'b'):value2, (1,'c'):value3}
```

because all of them have `1` as the first element of the tuple key. One way is to use a `for` and `if`:

```
for key in my-dict:
    if key[0]==1:
       do something
```

However, my actual dictionary  and data are very huge and this method takes a lot of time. Is there any other way to efficiently do this?

Comment: What you want is a true 2-dimensional mapping; `dict` is strictly 1-dimensional. You might try a nested `dict` where (for example) `d[1]['a'] == my_dict[(1,'a')]`.

Comment: You might be better off structuring this as a nested dictionary. Something like `{1:{'a' :value1, 'b':value2}}`. Then you just need to do a lookup for 1 on the outer dictionary. With how you have things set up, you'll need to do manual iteration to gather results.

Comment: The problem with nesting is you can't easily sum a bunch of nested Counters but you can easily sum a bunch of Counters with tuples as keys.  It needs to be awkward syntax on one end or the other I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose out on the benefits of creating a dictionary if you have to search through all its keys again. A good solution would be to create another dictionary That holds all keys which start with the correct first element.

```
my_dict={(1,'a'):'value1', (1,'b'):'value2', (1,'c'):'value3', (2,'a'):'value4', 
(2,'b'):'value5',(3,'a'):'value6'}

from collections import defaultdict

mapping = defaultdict(list) #You do not need a defaultdict per se, i just find them more graceful when you do not have a certain key.

for k in my_dict:
    mapping[k[0]].append(k)
```

Mapping now looks like this:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {1: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
             2: [(2, 'a'), (2, 'b')],
             3: [(3, 'a')]})
```

Now Just use the dictionary to lookup the keys needed in your original dictionary.

```
first_element = 1
#Now just use the lookup to do some actions
for key in mapping[first_element]:
    value = my_dict[key]
    print(value)
    #Do something
```

Output:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments and answers!

Answer (score 2):

The [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) built-in type maps hashable values to arbitrary objects. In your dictionary, the tuples `(1, 'a')`, `(1, 'b')`, etc. all have different hashes.

You could try using [Pandas multi-indexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) to accomplish this. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) is a good example.

Alternatively, as one of the comments suggested, a nested dictionary may be more appropriate here. You can convert it from `my_dict` via

```
from collections import defaultdict

nested_dict = defaultdict(dict)  # not necessary, but saves a line
for tup_key, value in my_dict.items():
    key1, key2 = tup_key
    nested_dict[key1][key2] = value
```

Then something like `nested_dict[1]` would give you

```
{'a':value1, 'b':value2, 'c':value3}
```